# Installing Pods in a Ionic project (iOS platform)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

What did you do?

- I use the command "pod install" inside an iOS project generated by ionic. I know that this problem is happening because when I created the iOS platform code I used "sudo" and now it's kind of protected. If I try to add iOS platform without "sudo" it throws me another error related to permissions of some Cordova files.

What did you expect to happen?

- I just expected to install Pods because I need to install OneSignal framework.

What happened instead?

- Problems with permissions.

#### Stack

```
        CocoaPods : 1.2.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.0.14.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.12.5 (16F73)
       Xcode : 8.3.3 (8E3004b)
         Git : git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 41b515530ae13b6eb0bf18252ba1b05f515afbe6
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.2.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'Palabra de Vida España' do
    project 'Palabra de Vida España.xcodeproj'
    pod 'OneSignal', '2.5.4'
end
```

#### Error

```
Errno::EACCES - Permission denied - /Users/oriollopezperez/Documents/wolspain-app/platforms/ios/Pods
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/sandbox.rb:58:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:184:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:184:in `sandbox'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:138:in `installer_for_config'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:38:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: install nvm and you won't need sudo

Comment: @jcesarmobile I installed nvm with "curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash" and now, when I use ionic or cordova commands, terminal is frozen, it doesn't do anything.

Edit: Same error, nothing new.

Comment: You probably also created the project with sudo, so you'll have that problem on that project. Try to create a new one (without sudo) and move your www content there

Comment: @jcesarmobile I installed "ionic start myApp tabs" and then "ionic cordova platform add ios" at it throws the same error with permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Install and update cocoapods to fix the problem

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```